# Can't import youtubesearchpython into my code

Tags: python, django

```
Pip install youtube-search-python
```

And than when i try :

```
from youtubesearchpython import *
```

I see an error tells me that the module not found
What is the problem

Comment: If you use pycharm then I know how to install it easily

Comment: So tell me please

Comment: When you hover over what you need to import then install package comes up and when you click on it it wil install

Answer (score 0):

Are you using anaconda or conda ? If not you can install it [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html).
I would recommend to built an environment (here : `myenvname`) first with all the available packages you need. You will be able to install `youtube-search-python` with `conda-forge` channel.

```
conda create --name myenvname --channel=conda-forge youtube-search-python
conda install -n myenvname python
conda install -n myenvname scipy
conda install -n myenvname matplotlib
...
conda activate myenvname
```

After that you choose your `myenvname` for your environment with specific packages installed. Feel free to consult the conda documentation available at the same link as above.

Comment: I'm using vsc only

Comment: You can do the same thing using vsc. Top right on the window, select interpreter, and if you create your virtual environment as I told you in the answer (with conda and so on) you can select it there. And your import library will work.